# Search a name in Mysql table with or without a leading space

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table in which some have  names with a leading space and some names don't have it.

I have a variable `$name` which I have to match with a name in table, this `$name` doesn't have a leading space. How should I write my query in this case?

Comment: `LTRIM(name)` will remove the space, then you can match `LTRIM(name) LIKE "Smith"`

Comment: It's surprisingly hard to find a duplicate for this question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trim the leading and trailing space on each value.

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE TRIM(colName) = '$name'
```

`TRIM` trims leading and trailing
`LTRIM` trims leading space
`RTRIM` trims trailing space

Comment: I used ltrim(colname) instead of trim as I just wanted to remove leading space.Thank You

Comment: what's the problem of using `TRIM`? :)

Comment: I guess ,`trim` would remove all the spaces and some names do have spaces in between them so that's why.

Comment: I'd still give `LIKE` a go. :)

Comment: `TRIM` will not remove spaces in between.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE colName = '$name' Or colName = concat(' ' , '$name')`
. The main reason is index usage: If you filter on a computed column `ltrim(colName)` the DB engine can't use any index on colName. My suggestion would allow the use of an index on colName.

Comment: how much this query is efficient in compared to answer given by john woo?

Comment: Well, `WHERE TRIM(colName) = '$name'` means that the DB has to evaluate `TRIM(colName)` on ALL rows and return the matching. If you use the `OR`ed alternative with exact match, an index seek would return faster (provided there is an index!). Hard to tell how much...